# Permission error to use private git repo in package.json for npm install using https protocol

Tags: git, npm

I'm using this url in package.json in dependancies using  https

```
<private repo>:"git+https://<token>:x-oauth-basic@github.com/<org>/<private repo>"
```

Also I have tried with this one

```
<private repo>:"git+https://<token>:x-oauth-basic@github.com/<org>/<private repo>.git"
```

add only .git at the end

And I know token is valid Becz

When I'm cloning this repo using this below command on terminal working fine

```
git clone https://<token>:x-oauth-basic@github.com/<org>/<private repo>.git
```

So I'm getting error like this even though I'm not use `ssh` protocole

```
 npm ERR! Permission denied (publickey).
 npm ERR! fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
 npm ERR!
 npm ERR! Please make sure you have the correct access rights
 npm ERR! and the repository exists.
```

And I've created this token by selecting scopes `read:org,write:org`

Answer (score 2):

Check your version of NPM (npm -v).  There is a bug in NPM 2.7.4 (and maybe 2.7.5) that causes cloning of private repos to fail.

See: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/1323

I ran into this today with 2.7.4 installed.  I updated to the latest nodejs which brought down NPM 2.11.3, and I was able to get a private repo over git+https with token just fine.